# PasteSpecial VBA with format and range

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I have the following Code:

```
Sub test()
    Dim objData As DataObject ' Set a reference to MS Forms 2.0
    Dim sHTML As String
    Dim sSelAdd As String
    Dim rng As Range

    Cells(2, 7).Value = Cells(2, 7).Value 
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 7)

    Set objData = New DataObject
    sHTML = rng.Text
    objData.SetText sHTML
    objData.PutInClipboard
    ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Unicode Text"
End Sub
```

However I was wondering if there is a way to use this method:

```
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Unicode Text"
```

In some sort of a way where I define the Paste range as well. It seems the text which is being pasted is copied in multiple cells overwriting other ones.

Comment: I believe you will need to select the destination before performing the paste.  What exactly is the aim of this code though?

Comment: This is the only line you need: `Cells(2, 7).Value = Cells(2, 7).Value `

Answer (score 1):

You could paste it to the currently selected cell, which can be very intuitive and useful for the end user:

```
Selection.PasteSpecial Format:="Unicode Text"
```

If you want to define the location in the code then you could do something like this:

```
Range("A1").PasteSpecial Format:="Unicode Text"
```

---

Edit: Today I learned that Range.PasteSpecial is different from Worksheet.PasteSpecial.

It looks like you can choose where you want to paste the data by selecting the cell before attempting to paste. This appears to do the trick for me:

```
Sub test()
    Dim objData As DataObject ' Set a reference to MS Forms 2.0
    Dim sHTML As String
    Dim sSelAdd As String
    Dim rng As Range

    Cells(2, 7).Value = Cells(2, 7).Value 
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 7)

    Set objData = New DataObject
    sHTML = rng.Text
    objData.SetText sHTML
    objData.PutInClipboard
    rng.Select '<----Add this line.
    ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Unicode Text"
End Sub
```

Comment: solution Range("G2").PasteSpecial Format:="Unicode Text" - gives an error: compile error: named argument not found

Comment: I edited my answer. Does the new version work for you?

Comment: If this other method is a solution to the question you asked here, please consider posting it as an answer so other people can benefit from what you've learned. If it isn't a solution to this question, then please look at my answer and consider accepting it if it satisfactorily answers the question that you asked.

Comment: wow relax not working today will post it once i have time/access to it not a priority in my life right now. Thanks fo the valuable input....

Comment: Sorry, I didn't intend to be rude. Your previous comment came off to me as one of those "Nevermind I figured it out"-type comments that people tend to leave as their last comment before abandoning their question entirely. In the future, I'll be sure to give people more time before I attempt to press the matter.

Comment: Also, and I really don't intend to sound like a jerk here, but the different method you posted is exactly the same as the one I posted. We just used different range objects. In fact, if the active sheet in your example is GridData, then my _rng.select_ and your _Worksheets("GridData").Range("G1")_ are precisely equivalent statements.

Answer (score 0):

I found this to work:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
 Dim objData As DataObject ' Set a reference to MS Forms 2.0
    Dim sHTML As String
    Dim sSelAdd As String
    Dim rng As Range

    Cells(1, 7).Value = Cells(1, 7).Value
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 7)

    Set objData = New DataObject
    sHTML = rng.Text
    objData.SetText (sHTML)
    objData.PutInClipboard
    rng.Select
   Worksheets("GridData").Range("G1").Select
    ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:= _
 "Unicode Text"
End Sub
```